# Compare Matching Element using single query in Iqueryable

Tags: c#, iqueryable

I am trying to compare two List of `UserGroup` from two different Table using a single query ie, by not hitting DB multiple times.

currently I am fetching all assigned `UserGroup` in one query, and comparing with all allowed `Usergroup` in other query.

```
  var query = _context.AppSubOperationUserGroupMappings.Where(filterPredicate)
                                                             .Select(x => x.UserGroup)
                                                             .ToList();

  var allowedUserGroups = _context.Users.Where(x => x.Id == userId)
                                              .Select(x => x.UserGroupUserMappings.Select(y => y.UserGroup))
                                              .First()
                                              .ToList();

  return query.Any(a => allowedUserGroups.Any(b => b.Id == a.Id));
```

How can I merge them into single Query?

Comment: Have you tried simply dropping the `.ToList` in your queries. That should result in a single DB query.

Answer (score 0):

Remove **ToList** and **First**, use **Join** and **SelectMany**

```
var query = _context.AppSubOperationUserGroupMappings.Where(filterPredicate)
    .Select(x => x.UserGroup);

var allowedUserGroups = _context.Users.Where(x => x.Id == userId)
    .SelectMany(x => x.UserGroupUserMappings, (x, y) => y.UserGroup);

return query
    .Join(
        allowedUserGroups,
        x => x.Id,
        x => x.Id,
        (x, y) => false) // doesn't matter what to select
    .Any();
```